# time.time() float object has no attribute Error

Tags: python, time

I am trying to time how long it takes different list sizes take to be sorted by a sort code I wrote.
I create a random list of numbers from 1 to a thousand. Then I move larger numbers to the back slowly by comparing the number to the number in the next position. I move through the whole list like this then, check if the list is sorted and if not repeat the process.  Using a for loop I am attempting to calculate the time it takes the code to sort a list of increasing sizes.
Here is the code:

```
import random
import time
sizeOfLargestList = int(input("Enter: "))

def isItSorted(list):
    for postion in range(0, len(list)-1):

        if(list[postion] > list[postion+1]):
            return False
    return True


def sortTwoVar(list, position):
    if(list[position] < list[position+1]):
        return True
    elif(list[position] == list[position+1]):
        return "Equal"
    else:
        return False


def loopSort(list):
    numberOfEquivilentNumbers = 1
    for position in range(0, len(list)-1):
        sorted = sortTwoVar(list, position)
        if(sorted == False):
            for set in range(numberOfEquivilentNumbers):
                numberMoving = list.pop(position-set)
                list.insert(position+1, numberMoving)
            numberOfEquivilentNumbers = 1
        elif(sorted == "Equal"):
            numberOfEquivilentNumbers += 1
        else:
            numberOfEquivilentNumbers = 1


def sorter(length):
    list = []
    for i in range(0,length):
        list.append(random.randint(0,1000))
    print("2")
    start = time.time()
    while(isItSorted(list) == 0):
        loopSort(list)
    print("3")
    end = time.time()
    return end-start


for listSize in range(0,sizeOfLargestList):
    print("1")
    time = sorter(listSize)
    print("List Size:" , listSize , "Time To Execute:" , time)
```

Whenever I try to create a list longer then zero attributes I get an output like so:

```
Enter: 2
1
2
3
List Size: 0 Time To Execute: 0.0
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Codes\Sort Code restart.py", line 53, in <module>
    time = sorter(listSize)
  File "C:\Python Codes\Sort Code restart.py", line 43, in sorter
    start = time.time()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time'
```

How can I fix my time element.

Comment: You probably have a variable named `time`. I can also see one named `list`.

Comment: `time = sorter(listSize)` - like that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Easy mistake. Just change the variable named 'time' to something else as the interpreter thinks your referring to the time import. like so:

```
for listSize in range(0,sizeOfLargestList):
    print("1")
    time_t = sorter(listSize)
    print("List Size:" , listSize , "Time To Execute:" , time_t)
```